# How to style table with only vertical cell spacing?

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table in my HTML yet I only want vertical spacing as it doesn't look right with the 25px horizontally. I can see no attribute in HTML to do this so is it possible?
Thanks in Advance,
Dean

EDIT: 
I have a table with cellspacing all the way around of 25px. I would only like vertical cellspacing of 25px.

Comment: I do not understand. Can you rephrase?

Comment: See my edit, I hope this has made it more understandable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `cellpadding` attribute, which I assume you're talking about, will only take a number and use it as pixels between the cell wall and content. You'll have to come up with a workaround, depending on your layout you may want to use a `<div>` instead, or if there aren't any borders around the cells you can add `style='padding-bottom:25px'` to it to create the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this in the < head > section, just after the head tag opening of your page:
This should do the work:

```
<style type="text/css">
td { margin: 25px 0px; } /* tells the table to have 25 
px on top and bottom, zero px on left and right */
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner `<table>` element solution (useful for in-lining styles).

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 20px;
}

th {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

th, td {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Vehicle     <th>No. of Wheels  <th>Rep (0-10)
    <tr>
      <td>Skateboard  <td>4              <td>7
    <tr>
      <td>BMX         <td>2              <td>6
    <tr>
      <td>Unicycle    <td>1              <td>-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this:

```
border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
```

Be aware that IE6 [has a problem with transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2506868/41688).