# css cut-out border/shape around element

Tags: html, css

I'm not even sure this is possible, I'm looking to make a see-trough "border"/cut-out around an element. Like in the image below, the point is to make the background show between the magenta element in the centre and the grey elements.

[image: desired result]

So far all I have managed is a solid colour border around the magenta element. Using the following class, this gives me the desired result but only on a white background.

```
.app.center {
  height: 40px;
  width: 28px;
  z-index: 5000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px white;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6deaazy/1/) for my entire CSS.

Setting a transparent border as suggested in the comments does not solve my problem (tested in FF40). I am trying to create a transparent gap around my middle div element (the magenta one). Setting a transparent border on this element does not work.

I am looking for a way to clip the sibling divs that fall behind the middle div so a small piece of the background is visible on either side of the middle element that follows the edge/shape of the centre element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a transparent border with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506844/how-do-i-make-a-transparent-border-with-css)

Comment: Well, problem is that a "transparent border" will make the border display what is behide it : the other gray figures.

Comment: is it a background-image? or a map?

Comment: In the design I posted here it's a map. The element with the 3 is supposed to inform the user of the element they clicked on can be used in another application. The background can be anything really, a map is most common as I'm working on a GIS application.

Comment: Close-voters, give it a break please. This is **not** a duplicate of that question which you are voting on. Reading first would make it clear. @ArnoldWiersma: you could improve your question by providing more clarity and explaining why it is not a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is basically impossible. That's why I am trying to provide an answer :-)

My solution will not work on IE, and limits you to use primary colors in the elements. As far as I know, it's the only way to get this result.

The trick is to use a blend mode, that translates gray into transparent. And the borders of the element will be gray, so will show the underlying background

```css
.bkg {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border: solid 1px black;
 background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, white 0px, lightblue 40px);
}

.button {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 20%;
 border: solid 10px gray;
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 80px;
}

#bt1 {
 left: 40px;
 top: 20px;
 background-color: red;
}

#bt2 {
 left: 80px;
 top: 90px;
 background-color: rgb(255,0,255);
}

.panel {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}
```

```html
<div class="bkg"></div>
<div class="panel">
    <div class="button" id="bt1">-1-</div>
    <div class="button" id="bt2">-2-</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is as close to what I was looking for as technically possible, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If your purpose could be met with a *"faux"*-transparency, then you could make use of the `border-image`. However, this is not a true solution. Also, you would lose `border-radius` when you use a `border-image`.

The trick is to use as `border-image` the same image that you use for your `background-image` on lower-layer div or body. This will give the *"illusion"* of transparency clipping through the sibling `div`s which are at a lower-level.

**Example**:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lndoe.jpg); }
.sphere {
    position: relative; background-color: #444;
    left: 200px; top: 100px; height: 100px; width: 200px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px; border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; color: white;
}
.app {
    position: absolute; transform-origin: center 75px; background: #cc4489;
    border-radius: 5px; left: 72px; top: -72px; height: 64px; width: 52px;
}
div.sphere > .app:first-child {
    transform: scale(0.9) rotate(-30deg);
    background: #adabae; top: -72px; 
}
div.sphere > .app:last-child {
    transform: scale(0.9) rotate(30deg);
    background: #79787a; top: -72px;
}
.app.center {
    height: 64px; width: 52px; z-index: 5000;
    background-clip: padding-box; background-origin: padding-box;
    border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lndoe.jpg) 10;
    border-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class=" sphere">
    <div class="app"></div>
    <div class="app center">3</div>
    <div class="app"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/aoh8vc8v/

As applied to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/L6deaazy/3/

**Disclaimer**: This is *faux* clipping. `clip-path` and `mask` could be better put to use.

Comment: This is getting closer to what I'm looking to achieve. Sadly this will not work as the background is dynamic content so I have no way to create the effect.