# How to make this triangle see through?

Tags: css

I had a look at how to make shapes in CSS, I have figured out how to make squares etc. see through however I can't seem to keep the outer border but make the background of the shape see through?

CSS

```
.triangle{
    width: 0;
    heigth: 0;
    border-left: 250px solid transparent;
    border-right: 250px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 400px solid #555;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -45px;
    left: -10px;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a transparent border with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506844/how-do-i-make-a-transparent-border-with-css)

Comment: I don't think so, so what I am trying to do is have the outline of the trianlge be coloured #E55C5C and the inside of the triangle be transparent

Comment: Because of the way you're rendering the triangle, that isnt really possible. The entire thing is made of borders, so where would the background-color go?

Comment: Right so how would I render the trianlge to have a transparent background and coloured borders?

Comment: Use an SVG to do this